# How could I get the arrow image to be placed on the left of "answer1"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the code, a bit messy, going to fix it up after this is answered.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="" onmouseover="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='graphics/websites/labyrinth/labyrintharrow1.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='';"> 
                website screenshot service 
                <img src="" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: absolute;" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrnvrdub/

And thanks for the help it's greatly appreciated.

Edit: all of the replies work fantastically but when I try to adjust the size of the image, I have tried using both css and html, an empty square is in the image's place when the link isn't hovered.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/csewukgs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option to Fabio's solid answer is to use a background image.

```
<a class="bullet" href="">Answer1</a>
<a class="bullet" href="">Answer2</a>

.bullet {
    background: url("path/to/image.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding-left: 18px;  //width of image, plus some extra spacing
}
```

The benefit being that if you have a list of links, you do not need to add an `img` element to every one.

One caveat, if the image is non-decorative and actually communicates something important, do use an `img` element with an appropriate `title` attribute, which is helpful to screen-reader users.

```
<a class="bullet" href="">Answer1 <img src="..." title="The correct answer"></a>

// use Fabio's float:left solution
```

Answer (score 2):

delete the inline style and add this

```
a img{float:left}
```

you may want to add some margin as well, but you'll get the idea

Note: it's a good idea to give a class to that img so you don't have to be this generic. Like

```
.bullet{float:left}
```

HTML

```
<img class="bullet" src="uyourimage" id="place-holder-1"  />
```

Comment: Sorry to seem stupid but I'm a little lost on how I would set this up.

Comment: simply delete the style in your code and add the class, then use a stylesheet. If this is the only element with CSS you'll use (quite unlikely), you can add the code I gave you inside your style declaration just as you have it now. Anyways, there are many ways to do what you want, this is just one of them

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but now whenever I try to adjust the size of the image, I tried using both css and html for that, an empty square will be in it's spot when not hovered.

Comment: because you have ythis line:

onmouseout="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='';"> 

which has an empty src. I thought you wanted that by design. If not, I don't understand why are you using that on hover JS, quite probably you don't even need it

Comment: I had tried getting rid of it and it stopped the hovering effect completely, anyway around this?

Comment: again, I don't know what you want to achieve, as in what kind of hover effect you want. It sounds like you want to replace the image on hover. If that's the case, add the "on hover" image location inside that empty src. Then again, don't know what are you trying to achieve, so just guessing

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. What I'm aiming for is that a question is asked and when you hover over an answer in this case answer1, an arrow appears next to it and when you stop hovering over the answer the arrow disappears showing that it's no longer selected. Mainly aesthetic rather than having an actual function.

Comment: I see. Well, jbarreiros posted another solution you might be interested in, specially since it's only decorative (is the one I use myself for this kind of situations, btw). I strongly recommend using this solution instead, where your code will be a lot simpler. To add to jbarreiros's code, just add

`.bullet { background: transparent none;
    padding-left: 18px;  //width of image, plus some extra spacing
}
`.bullet:hover {background: url("path/to/image.png") no-repeat 0 0%;}
`
This way you'll have a lot less and way better code. If you want to continue your path, lmk and I'll tell you how

Comment: Am I doing something wrong because the empty square is still there. I edited the question and added and example of the problem at the bottom by the way.

Comment: If you think it'd be better just to post this as another question so I can stop wasting you're time I'm fine with that. I truly am sorry for being thick.

Comment: try this code http://jsfiddle.net/mubyqj7k/ . I've used any image so you can actually see it, but you'll need to replace it with your image and then adjust the padding-left declaration

Comment: That fixes it completely! Though leaves one more concern how would I adjust the size of the image?

Comment: Updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mubyqj7k/1/ . Basically, adjust the background size value. First number is height (use the height of your image or even a different size) and then auto so it scales proportionally. You can do it otherwise, use auto and width of image

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything is working as needed. Very sorry for wasting your time. Have a good night, or day!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/1Latpnzn/2/

It assumes that you want to shift the text to the right to make room for the image. By setting the placeholder to be as follows:

```
#place-holder-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

reordering the html:

```
<a href="" id="hover-link">
    <img id="place-holder-1" />
    <span>Answer1</span>
</a>
```

and removing the `position: absolute;` image can be positioned to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the position from absolute to inline block and move the image before the "answer 1" text that will work, and to get it to be aligned with the text you can add the vertial-align:bottom style

```
<a href=""
  onmouseover="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='graphics/websites/labyrinth/labyrintharrow1.png';"
  onmouseout="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='';">
  <img src="" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: inline-block; vertical-align:bottom" />
      Answer1
</a>
```